# Clear value in Pandas based on two index value

Tags: python, pandas

Through the filtering process, I got this table.

|  | Index | Next_Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 559 | 559 | 717 | 1 |
| 856 | 856 | 950 | 1 |

Based on the table I know I need to set the value to -1 between **Index** and **Next_Index** (in my case, I need to set the value to -1 if my dataframe index is between 559 and 717, as well as the index is between 856 and 950). The outcome should be the same as

```
df.loc[559:717, ("value")] = -1
df.loc[856:950, ("value")] = -1
```

I am not sure how can I could get this done given I have the pandas table. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I find the programmic way

```
for index, row in cleardf.iterrows():
    startIndex = row['Index']
    endIndex = row['Next_Index']
    df.loc[startIndex:endIndex, "Value"] = -1
```

This loop would go through the table row by row and then set the original `df` to -1

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[559:717, "Value"] = -1
df.loc[856:950, "Value"] = -1
```